# Ruby Selenium Webdriver test script (need advice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, selenium

I have a little task to create ruby+webdriver test script. But I can use only ruby and webdriver. Can you give me some advice for how to do it without Rspec or test unit?
Also I need to use some OOP model to this test.

There is requirements below:

Test case

1. Run a browser
2. Clear browser cookies
3. Go to website
4. Click on "Find"
5. Enter keyword into search field and submit form
6. Parse 1st page with search results: store info given on the 1st page of search results as a structured data of the chosen by you type (i.e. hash of hashes or array of hashes, whatever structure handy to be parsed).
7. Make sure at least one attribute (title, objective, skills, etc) of each item  from parsed search results contains keyword. Log in stdout which freelancers and attributes contain keyword and which do not.
8. Click on random freelancer's title
9. Get into that freelancer's profile
10. Check that each attribute value is equal to one of those stored in the structure created in #6
11. Check whether at least one attribute contains keyword

Requirements:

1. Browser and keyword should be configurable. Test should run with any combination of them.
2. Imagine that this is not such a simple tiny task, but a big scalable project which can be extended. Hence, implement appropriate OOP model/approach.
3. Prove model/approach chosen.
4. Every action, every comparison result, etc should be logged accordingly (i.e. to stdout). Goal: when your script pass - detailed test-case steps should be looged into STDOUT, so anybody can read it and repeat exactly the same steps and verifications but manually.
5. Code should be well commented, so anybody can easily find out what action is being performed there and what is the purpose of those code blocks/methods/etc.

Currently I've finished 1-5 step and stuck on 6 step. I need to save a data of users in hash of hashes and only then do the next steps.

```
    # encoding: utf-8
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class Tests < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @keyword = "qa tester"
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "https://www.odesk.com"
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30

  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit

  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def test_1

    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Hire Freelancers").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "q").clear
    @driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys @keyword
    @driver.find_element(:css, "input.oSearchSubmit").click


  end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  While your question is well-detailed, it's also extremely broad and lacks code showing what you've tried.  I'd recommend looking that the [SO questions guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  You'll get better responses that way.  Beyond that, I'd dig in on the Selenium documentation (or even take a peek at [watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com)).

Answer (score 0):

As [orde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672197/orde) mentioned, your question is pretty broad, but you could at least get started on your step #6 by modifying your "test_1" method like so to parse the unordered list of search results:

```
def test_1
  @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
  @driver.find_element(:link, "Hire Freelancers").click
  @driver.find_element(:name, "q").clear
  @driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys @keyword
  @driver.find_element(:css, "input.oSearchSubmit").click
  results_list = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//ul[@class='oSearchResultsList']")
  individual_results = results_list.find_elements(:xpath, "//li[@class='oSearchResultItem']")
  individual_results.each do
    # do some parsing of each search result here
  end
end
```

At that point, you'll just have to decide which specific data elements you want to extract and populate in a hash (or whatever data structure you select).